# Is there historical evidence for the town of Nazareth existing prior to Jesus?

Tags: jesus, new-testament, geography

Is there historical evidence for the town of Nazareth prior to Jesus? Do we have maps or any other evidence such as inscriptions, emblems, etc?

Comment: You just asked an interesting and difficult question, congratulations. However, I'm not sure if you had the opportunity to have a look [here](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). Please do share your research on the topic asked, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Now getting to your question, apparently yes, there is some archaeological evidence on the site and the area of the present Nazareth, dating since the bronze/iron age. Debatable, of course. An interesting material [here](https://ehrmanblog.org/did-nazareth-exist/)

Comment: Although we have a close reason that suggests that questions not referencing a specific biblical texts are off topic, the [help/on-topic] states that historical context is on topic. For discussion w.r.t. the close reason, see https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3502/2672.

Comment: @Keelan It says "historical context (*with regards to a particular text*)." I think this would be better as a question on [History](https://history.stackexchange.com/) since the question is about Nazareth, not about the New Testament in particular

Comment: @ba while there is no text specifically mentioned in the question, Nazareth of course frequently occurs in the NT. I can agree that this question fits better on History.SE (and if OP agrees it can perhaps be migrated); I don't agree that it should be closed here, however.

Answer (score 1):

The best evidence is the archaeological evidence.  The best discussion I encountered was the Lexham Bible Dictionary (quoted below).  To do much better than this you would need to research the primary archaeological records related to Nazareth.

> NAZARETH (Ναζαρέτ, Nazaret; Ναζαρά, Nazara, Ναζαρέθ, Nazareth). A village in Lower Galilee that was Jesus’ childhood home; situated on a ridge 500 meters above sea level.
>
> History of Settlement
>
> Archaeology evidence shows that Nazareth was settled as early as the Middle Bronze Age and continued to be settled through the Iron Age. However, the city is not mentioned in literature prior to the New Testament; likewise, Josephus doesn’t mention it, even though it was located near Japha/Yaphia, a city he fortified during the First Revolt (Josephus, Vita, 230). The site appears to have been uninhabited in the centuries following the Assyrian conquest. Extensive remains have been uncovered from the second century BC, suggesting a significant population increase (possibly resettlement) under the Hasmonean rule. It is unlikely that there was any genealogical continuity between the inhabitants of the Hasmonean period and those of the Iron Age (Reed, Archaeology, 28–31).
>
> The village had a predominantly Jewish population until at least the fourth century AD, and probably until the early seventh century. There is no evidence of any permanent Roman military presence. Inscriptional evidence from Caesarea attests that priests were present in Nazareth following the First Revolt, suggesting that the site was regarded as ritually pure.

Koiter, I. W. K. (2016). Nazareth. In J. D. Barry, D. Bomar, D. R. Brown, R. Klippenstein, D. Mangum, C. Sinclair Wolcott, … W. Widder (Eds.), The Lexham Bible Dictionary. Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

Here is a reference to an inscription related to Nazareth being resettled before the first-century A.D.:

> A Hebrew inscription found at Caesarea lists Nazareth as one of the villages in which priestly divisions (cf. Luke 1:8–9) were resident after the Jewish revolt. Some scholars allege that this notice suggests a degree of piety attributed to Nazareth, which has not produced any archaeological remains with pagan symbolism. Indeed, the few remains found include Jewish stone vessels, simple pottery, and perhaps a ritual bath.

Perkins, P., Jonathan L. (2011). Nazareth. In M. A. Powell (Ed.), The HarperCollins Bible Dictionary (Revised and Updated) (Third Edition, p. 691). New York: HarperCollins.

I can't vouch for the source, but here is a link that claims an picture of the fragment and its reconstruction: http://www.mythicistpapers.com/2013/07/01/nazareth-the-caesarea-inscription-and-the-hand-of-god-pt-5/

Here's the link to another article about the inscription: http://www.mythicistpapers.com/Nazareth,%20the%20Caesarea%20Inscription,%20and%20the%20hand%20of%20God.pdf

However, this inscription dates after the first century.

Here's information about the first century A.D. synagogue: http://www.nazarethvillage.com/blog/2015/02/24/first-century-synagogues/

Here's artifacts from a 2nd century B.C. lamp shop near Nazareth: https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/ancient-cultures/daily-life-and-practice/an-ancient-jewish-lamp-workshop-in-the-galilee/

This site reports: "Approximately 80% of our excavated pottery dates from the Early Roman Period (1st Century BC-AD)."  http://www.nazarethvillage.com/blog/2015/02/23/pottery/

This site gives some references: http://www.doxa.ws/Jesus_pages/Nazareth1.html

> occupied since 7th century BC
>
> Despite Nazareth's obscurity (which had led some critics to suggest that it was a relatively recent foundation), archeology indicates that the village has been occupied since the 7th century B.C., although it may have experienced a 'refounding' in the 2d century b.c. " ([MJ]A Marginal Jew--Rethinking the Historical Jesus, (vol 1), p.300-301)...cites Meyers and Strange, Archeology, the Rabbis, and Early Christianity, Abingdon:1981. pp.56-57

Comment: Actually the Hebrew inscription found at Caesarea is from the 4th century and not from before the 1st century according to the book, "The Jesus Legend: A Case for the Historical Reliability of the Synoptic pg 247"

Comment: That inscription is also from Caesarea and references Nazareth.  It's easy to confuse the reference to 2nd century B.C. revolt with the 1st century A.D. revolt.

Comment: Can we find the reference to these? "Extensive remains have been uncovered from the second century BC, suggesting a significant population increase (possibly resettlement) under the Hasmonean rule."

Koiter, I. W. K. (2016). Nazareth. In J. D. Barry, D. Bomar, D. R. Brown, R. Klippenstein, D. Mangum, C. Sinclair Wolcott, … W. Widder (Eds.), The Lexham Bible Dictionary. Bellingham, WA: Lexham Press.

Comment: I didn't get your point. Are you trying to say that they found 2 inscriptions, one from before the 1st century and the other from the 4th century? Thanks

Comment: No, I'm saying that the description of the inscription was about priest settling in Nazareth after the revolt (which one not designated), and other articles wrote about Nazareth resettling in the second century B.C. after the revolt and destruction of the second temple.  That threw me off.

Comment: Sorry I still didn't get you. I am really interested in the inscription that says "Nazareth". Is this inscription from a time period prior to the 1st century AD?

Comment: Apparently, the inscription refers to priest settling in Nazareth after the revolt in 70 A.D. and the inscription is after that time.  In any case, the inscription is after the first century A.D.